# reducing the space between li's border and the text

Tags: css

i've the following code:

```
<ul>
<li style="border: 300 red dashed">hello</li>
</ul>
```

and get something like:

hello

---

i want to reduce the gap i.e, i want to collapse the border so that it touches the base of the word "hello"..
was i clear? :)
any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the line-height property and fiddle with the percentage until you like it:

```
<ul>
  <li style="border: 1px red dashed; line-height:80%;">hello</li>
</ul>
```

Also, did you really want a 300px border?

Comment: @almac: I'm glad it worked

@ILMV: I looked at the result of his original in a page and saw a huge border, created by this: "border: 300 red dashed"

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
<ul>
    <li style="border: 300 red dashed; padding-bottom:2px;">hello</li>
</ul>
```

Simply change 2px to be whatever you need.

Padding specifies the distance between the content and the border, it might be a benefit to look at the [CSS box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/images/boxdim.gif), I have mine pinned to my wall for reference.

Comment: hmmm..ur code increases the gap, rite?
i want to reduce the gap ILMV..so, i gave some negative padding..it didn't have any effect :(

Comment: Hmmm, can you tell me what line-height you are using?

Answer (score 2):

play with css padding

**Update:**

```
    <ul style="margin-bottom:0px;">
        <li style="border: 300 red dashed; ">hello</li>
     </ul>
```

Comment: the code u gave is used to give margin between ul elements and is no way related to my pro :)